# Understanding branch cut of the following function $(z^3+1)^{1/3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

I'm trying to understand branch cuts in complex analysis. Let's say I have the following function
$$f(z)=(z^3+1)^{1/3}.$$
I see that the branch points in this case are the solutions to the equation $z^3+1=0$ and this is $z=-1\vee z=e^{\pi i/3}\vee z=e^{-\pi i/3}$. I would like to find a suitable branch cut for the function and what I think is the following branch cut $[-1,\infty)$. I take from -1 to infinity since -1 is a branch point but I am not sure about that. I don't understand how to find branch cut very well so what I want is a good explanation on how to find suitable branch cuts and then I will try for some other functions.

NB: I know someone asked a similar question [Branch cuts for $(z^2+1)^{1/3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170915/branch-cuts-for-z211-3)
but for me I did not get any idea of branch cuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small circle around one of the zeros, the angle of $z^3+1$ increases by $2\pi$.  The angle of its cube root increases by $2\pi/3$, so $f(x)$ changes by a factor $e^{2i\pi/3}$.  So $f(x)$ is not well-defined, or at least not continuous, if that path is allowed.
Take a curved cut from $-1$, via $e^{i\pi/3}$, to $e^{-i\pi/3}$.  Then any allowed path that goes around one root goes around all three roots of $z^3+1$.  Each factor of $z^3+1$ increases in angle by $2\pi$, so $z^3+1$ increases in angle by $6\pi$.  Its cube root increases in angle by $2\pi$, so $f(z)$ takes a consistent cube root of $z^3+1$.

Comment: So when reading your great answer I can take my branch cut from $e^{i\pi/3}$ to $e^{-i\pi/3}?$

Comment: The cut needs to prevent any loop going between the roots.  So join up the roots by lines.